# Default value for struct parameter

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, default-value, static-initialization

Let's say I have the following struct:

```
struct myStruct
{
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;
 int w;
};
```

I want to initialize this struct to a default value when calling the following function. If it helps I'm looking for a simple zero initialization.

```
void myFunc(myStruct param={0,0,0,0})
{
 ...
}
```

This code however gives me compile error. I've tried VS2003 and VS2008.

**NOTE:** I have looked at other answers mentioning the use of constructor. However I *want* the user to see what values I'm using for initialization.

Comment: `myStruct param=myStruct{0,0,0,0}`?

Comment: @HighCommander4 nopes.

Comment: If you need fellow programmers to see the default values of `myStruct` (and that is the only reason you wish to define it as you have), I would add that information as a comment, rather than creating a default struct in the parameter list - a comment may be a little more elegant. Alternatively, you could instead pass a pointer to `myStruct` with a default param value of NULL, then check for NULL inside the method and create an empty struct if required.

Comment: @PLPiper I may end up doing that, but I was wondering if there was a way to fix this.

Comment: I assume the restriction to VS2003/VS2008 is the limiting factor for using an initializer list in your param set. What about a function?

Comment: @PLPiper I *really* don't think pointer is the right way. I'd rather use a constructor and leave a comment instead.

Comment: Eh.. function isn't gonna work without providing params to it to fulfill the visible value clause of your question. which I suppose would work, but you're one step away from a constructor at that point. oh well.

Comment: @jalf Mmmm.... Why didn't I think of this myself? Anyways... if you add this as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 6):

Adding **default constructor** in to your **myStruct** will solves your problem.

```
struct myStruct {
   myStruct(): x(0),y(0), z(0), w(0) { }   // default Constructor
   int x, y, z, w;
};
```

**Function declaration:**

```
void myFunc(myStruct param = myStruct());
```

Answer (score 3):

For modern C++ compilers which fully implement value-initilization it is enough to have the following value-initialized default value to zero-initiliaze data members of the myStruct:

```
myFunc(myStruct param=myStruct())
```

For other compilers you should to use something like this:

```
myStruct zeroInitilizer() {
   static myStruct zeroInitilized;
   return zeroInitilized;
}
myFunc(myStruct param=zeroInitilizer())
```

To avoid compiler specifics conside to use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm

Comment: I'd say nowadays `zeroInitializer()` is not necessary, your first solution should work. Anyway I'd make it inline and returning copy of local const variable initialized to zero by ` = {}` ....

Comment: What is the purpose of the `static` inside the `zeroInitializer` function?