# Default arguments in default constructor for members of type struct

Tags: c++, oop, struct, constructor

I have this code "for" a bank. It is organized in two structures for date, and personal information about person. The information about the bank account is organized in a class. I need to write a default constructor with predefined arguments. The class contains a data member of type struct and I don't know how to initialize the data member of type struct. Here is my code.

```
struct Date {
    int day, month, year;
};

struct Person {
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int IDnum[13];
    Date dateBirth;
};

class BankAccount {
public:
    BankAccount( ????Person p????, int s = 0, bool em = true, int sal = 0 ) {
        ??sth for Person p I guess??
        sum = s;
        employed = em;
        salary = sal;
    }
private:
    Person person;
    int sum;
    bool employed;
    int salary;
};
```

I would appreciate every help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307954/default-value-for-struct-parameter

Comment: yes I saw this post, but I didn't find it helpful because I didn't understand it. A constructor in a structure?

Comment: The difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is just default visibility: `public` vs `private`.

Comment: So when I write the constructors in the structures, do I need to set a predefined argument to Person p in the class constructor or should I leave it as it is: BankAccount( Person p, int s = 0, bool em = true, int sal = 0 ) ?

Comment: Don't use char arrays, use std::string.

Comment: Just write a default constructor for `Person`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same syntax you use when initializing a `struct`/`class` variable.

```
BankAccount(Person p = {"John", "Doe", {1,2,3,/*...*/}, {1,1,2000}}, int s = 0, bool em = true, int sal = 0 )
```

If some initializers are missing, like `Person p = {"John", "Doe"}`, then all  fields lacking initializers are zero-initialized.

It means you could even do `Person p = {}` to set all fields to zeroes.

Optionally you can write `Person{...}` instead of `{...}`, which is what @Curious did.

---

Also, if you're using C++, *please* use `std::string`s instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: "set all fields to zeroes" does this also apply to char arrays. I am not so sure that I understand, or it sets them to the '\0' or an empty string " "?

Comment: @Winston Both. All symbols are set to `'\0'` (aka `0`), which makes the string empty. (If by empty string you mean actual `""`, not a space `" "`.)

Comment: Yes, that is my bad, I didn't mean a space, only the empty string "".

Comment: "Also, if you're using C++, please use std::strings instead of char arrays."
Give an explanation please.

Answer (score 0):

Structs and classes are almost the same thing in C++, structs can have constructors which is what you should do in this situation

```
class BankAccount {
public:
    BankAccount(const Person& p = Person{...}, int s = 0, bool em = true, int sal = 0 )
            : person{p}, sum{s}, employed{em}, salary{sal} {}
private:
    Person person;
    int sum;
    bool employed;
    int salary;
};
```

---

You can also provide initializers for member variables in the class definition itself, for example

```
struct Something {
    int integer{1};
    bool boolean{false};
};
```

Comment: I don't like to be rude, but could you explain what do you mean with this: const Person& p = Person{...}. What does this signify Person{...}?

Comment: @Winston it would have the same meaning that the answer above does.  A call to a person constructor with the parameters it expects